# Why does time still show with UTC time zone instead of settings.TIME_ZONE?

Tags: python, django, datetime, pytz, django-timezone

I have a model that shows a short string in `__str__()` method of the model

```
def __str__(self):
    return "Scheduled at %s" % (self.date_time.strftime("%B %d %Y %I:%M %p"))
    #Output: <Task: Scheduled at September 30 2018 12:30 AM>
    # it should have been: <Task: Scheduled at September 29 2018 08:30 PM>
```

When I go to the *Django admin*, I see in the title **Task: Scheduled at September 30 2018 12:30 AM** and in the input it is filled with the correct `TIME_ZONE`: *20:30:00*

**settings.py**

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Etc/GMT+4'

USE_I18N = False

USE_L10N = False

USE_TZ = True
```

He keeps showing time with UTC time zone, however I set `TIME_ZONE='Etc/GMT+4` in my settings.

I want time data to be saved in database as UTC and show them with TIME_ZONE, in my case `Etc/GTM+4`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django converts datetimes when [displaying values with templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#time-zone-aware-output-in-templates). If you want to do the conversion in arbitrary blocks of code, use the [`localtime()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.localtime) helper:

```
from django.utils.timezone import localtime

def __str__(self):
    return "Scheduled at %s" % localtime(self.date_time).strftime("%B %d %Y %I:%M %p")
```

Comment: thank you! i set also the TIME_ZONE, is it redundant? `django.utils.timezone.localtime(date_time, pytz.timezone(settings.TIME_ZONE))`

Comment: It's redundant. The documentation says that the default value is the current time zone, which is the same as `TIME_ZONE` if you haven't activated another one.